# ¿Cómo llenar un array y que se vaya sumando?

Tags: java

Tengo un ejercicio que no acabo de encontrar el modo de resolver este problema y apenas encuentro información de ello...

Este es el enunciado:

> Programa que llena un array de 100 elementos con los valores :
> 0,1,1+2,1+2+3,1+2+3+4,...

> Fíjate que cada elemento es igual al anterior más un número

> Despues el usuario entra un número y el programa muestra el valor del
> elemento que se encuentra en esta posición.

> Validar la entrada del usuario para que controle las posibles excepciones

> Salida del programa:

> Entra un número entre 0 y 99 : 10

> La suma de los primeros 10 números naturales es 55

Estoy bastante frustrado ya que no se como proceder... hasta ahora lo único que he llegado a conseguir es lo siguiente:

```
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] num = new int[100];

    int num_user = 0;

    do {

        if (num_user < 0 || num_user >= 100) {
            System.out.println("Entrada inválida");
        }

        System.out.println("Entra un número entre 0 y 99 ");
        num_user = teclado.nextInt();
    }

    while (num_user >= 100 || num_user < 0);

    for (int i = 0; i <= num_user; i++) {
        
    }
```

Comment: Para empezar, primero tienes que hacer un array de 100 elementos en el que el primer elemento es 0, y a partir de ahí, cada elemento es la suma del anterior más su posición en el array (contando que los arrays empiezan en cero, el segundo elemento está en la posición 1, con lo que sería 0 + 1 = 1, etc..). Luego, antes de comprobar si el número introducido es correcto, tendrás que introducir el número, digo yo, no? Y con el número introducido solo tienes que ir al array a esa posición para obtener el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
// Creamos un array de tamaño 100 para guardar los datos
int[] arr = new int[100];
    //Con un bucle for, recorremos el array
    for(int i = 0;i <= 99;i++)
    {
// Declaramos un acumulador que se utilizará más adelante
      int acum = 0;
      //Declaramos otro bucle donde iteraremos sobre el número actual (desde el 0 hasta i)
      for(int j = 0;j <= i;j++)
      {
        //Le sumamos el valor de j al acumulador.
        acum += j;
      }
      // Por último, asignamos el valor del acumulador al array en la posición i
      arr[i] = acum;
    }
```

Ya, lo último que necesitarías es la parte de la pregunta por consola y acceder al elemento i del array.

Edit: He encontrado una forma mucho más rápida que iterar con dos bucles for.

```java
    int[] arr = new int[100];
    for(int i = 0;i <= 99;i++)
    {
      /*
      Con el operador ternario (bool ? If Yes : If No) lo que hacemos es comprobar 
      si i == 0. Si lo es, le ponemos como valor el 0, si no, accedemos al valor anterior
      y le sumamos el valor actual de i.
      */
      arr[i] = (i == 0) ? 0 : arr[i - 1] + i;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Sergio! tu explicación me ha ayudado mucho a entender este ejercicio!

Comment: Un palcer @Azumay404! Me alegro de haberte sido de ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

La solución es bastante sencilla.

Como dice el enunciado, primero debes llenar un array con los valores, siendo el siguente la sumatoria del indice anterior.

Entonces lo Primero que deberias hacer es calcular el array necesario con los números de esta manera.

```
 int[] arr = new int[100];
 int prevSum = 0;
 int num_user;
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     prevSum += i;
     arr[i] = prevSum;
 }
```

Donde usamos `prevSum` como el acumulador de la suma anterior.

lo siguiente que resta es añadir la lógica de solicitar al usuario el ingreso de un número, pero ademas imprimirlo a partir de nuestro array ya generado. Quedando de esta manera:

```
do {

    if (num_user < 0 || num_user >= 100) {
        System.out.println("Entrada inválida");
    }

    System.out.println("Entra un número entre 0 y 99 ");
    num_user = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println(arr[num_user]);
}
```

Entonces si el usuario ingresa un 10 como número de entrada el programa imprimirá el 55 esperado.